# C# - Returning an Enum? from a static extension method

Tags: c#, generics, enums, extension-methods

I've added some extension methods for strings to make working with some custom enums easier.

```
public static Enum ToEnum<T>(this string s)
{
    return (Enum)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), s);
}

public static bool IsEnum<T>(this string s)
{
    return Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), s);
}
```

Note -- because of limitations of generic type constraints, I have to write the methods like the above.  I would love to use T ToEnum(this string s) where T: Enum to avoid the cast after making the call ... but no can do.

In any event, I figured it would be nice to extend this concept a little bit to return Enum? in those instances where a method signature can accept various nullable enums.

```
public static Enum? ToEnumSafe<T>(this string s)
{
    return (IsEnum<T>(s) ? (Enum)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), s) : null);
}
```

However, this is a no-go due to compiler errors.

```
error CS0453: The type 'System.Enum' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable<T>'
```

I have to admit I'm a bit confused here as Enum? should be a legitimate return value, no?.  I tried something similar, but end up with the same error.

```
public static T? ToEnumSafe<T>(this string s)
{
    return (IsEnum<T>(s) ? (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), s) : null);
}
```

I even decided to rewrite the methods to remove the generics and I get more of the same:

```
public static bool IsEnum(this string s, Type T)
{
    return Enum.IsDefined(T, s);
}
public static Enum? ToEnumSafe(this string s, Type T)
{
    return (IsEnum(s, T) ? (Enum)Enum.Parse(T, s) : null);
}
```

Am I missing something really stupid here?

Comment: Ahh yes.  I see now my dumb mistake.  Enum is derived from ValueType which itself is a Reference Type as its derived from object.  

I think I must have been running short on brainpower at the time ;0

The confusing part is that there's nothing preventing the use of a concrete enum type -- just no can do on a more generic implementation:

    public enum Test { a, b };
    public static class Tester
    {
        public static Test? GetTest()
        {
            return (true == true ? (Test?)Test.a : null);
        }
    }


Thanks to all responders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
public static T? ToEnumSafe<T>(this string s) where T : struct
{
    return (IsEnum<T>(s) ? (T?)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), s) : null);
}
```

Comment: How would you handle this if you wanted to igore the case? i.e.  pass in "monkey" with the enum lookup type being "Monkey" using your code?

Comment: @Haroon `Enum.Parse` has an overload that takes Type, string, and a boolean representing case sensitivity of an operation.

Comment: Finally, this was what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: This is beautiful, how can someone come up with that? ))

Answer (score 3):

You can actually do somewhat better than this - with a bit of work.

Although C# doesn't support generic constraints to say that T must be an enum type, the CLR does. I have a project called [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody) which is a library of "useful things to do with an enum." I suspect it already copes with what you want (so long as you only need to use the *names* in the enum, not the string representations of the integer values). Although it doesn't have `IsDefined(string)`, it does have `TryParse` which will do the same job.

See [this blog post](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/09/10/generic-constraints-for-enums-and-delegates.aspx) for more details.

As to why `Enum?` isn't a valid return type - `System.Enum` itself is a reference type (just like `System.ValueType`), so it's already nullable. You can only use `?` with non-nullable value types.

Comment: I was googling to link to UnconstrainedMelody. Fortunately, you came around just at the right time :)

Comment: Awesome... this is a library that I hadn't come across.  Will be checking it out.

Comment: The link to the blog post is invalid now.

Comment: @PhilippM: Fixed. I'm hoping there'll be a mass replacement at some point, but I'm not sure of the plans.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Enum ToEnum<T>(this string s)
{
    return (Enum)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), s);
}
```

should be

```
public static T ToEnum<T>(this string s)
{
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), s);
}
```

can also fix the following

```
public static Enum? ToEnumSafe<T>(this string s)
{
    return (IsEnum<T>(s) ? (Enum)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), s) : null);
}
```

to

```
public static T? ToEnumSafe<T>(this string s)
    where T : struct
{
    return (IsEnum<T>(s) ? (T?)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), s) : null);
}
```

Comment: `return (IsEnum<T>(s) ? (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), s) : null);` won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

An Enum is no distinct Type in .Net it is just a placeholder for a concrete value type (int in case you didn't specify otherwise).

That means you cant have it as type declaration at all (regardless of static extention method or not).

Comment: Yes you can. System.Enum is a valid type in itself - but it's a reference type rather than a value type, hence "Enum?" doesn't work.

Comment: Well lets say you can't have it as a type for the purpose the original author wanted it to have. Because other than the stuff it inherits from ValueType and its interfaces it has no own non-static methods or properties.